# How was the exact time of Brexit computed?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

According to [this article](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/brexit-latest-news-theresa-may-eu-withdrawal-bill-date-time-law-march-2019-government-talks-a8047661.html):

> The Prime Minister announced plans to amend the EU Withdrawal Bill to
>   make it absolutely clear that Britain’s exit will come at **11pm on
>   Friday 29 March 2019.**

**11 PM is GMT**, as specified in [this article](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-41936428).

> She said the EU Withdrawal Bill would be amended to formally commit to
>   Brexit at 23:00 GMT on Friday 29 March 2019.

While the date is [article 50 triggering date](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-39422353) + 2 years, the time seems quite strange (why not the end of day / 12.00 AM?).

It seems as it is chosen to make the end of the day one time zone ahead (CET) or maybe it is related to  British Summer Time: `BST= GMT + 1h`, but could not find any official reference to clarify this aspect.

**Question:** How was the time of Brexit computed?

Comment: BST doesn't start until the [31st of March](https://www.google.com/search?&q=When+does+BST+start+in+the+UK+2019) in 2019.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

11pm GMT is [midnight in Brussels](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/brexit-talks-timeline-david-davis-and-european-unions-michel-barnier-to-meet-in-brussels-on-monday-a3567696.html).

Comment: This was confirmed on bbc r4 news.